# thre's a whole empty block and meta tags under my <body>

Tags: html, utf-8

My html file looks like below and the website is in Vietnamese so I use utf-8 for encoding.
But when I view the file in Chrome, under body tag, there is a huge empty block "     " and all the meta tags are also in the body.
I dont understand why I write all meta tags in the head tag but they appeared in body tag ....

Is there anything to do with utf-8 encoding. And whats the huge block? Can somebody help me? Thank you!!!

```
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />        
    <meta name="description" content="something ...." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="something... />

    <link href="tablestyle.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="hinhanh.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <title>mypage.com</title>
</head>

<body>
         Content here


    </body>
```

Comment: You do have a `<html>` element, right? (And a doctype?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the encoding of your code file. set your file's encoding to "UTF-8 Without BOM" with notepad++...

Comment: I think it's because of [BOM character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which is sent to the chrome.